# What am I doing wrong with the TreeMap<node>?

Tags: java, nodes, huffman-code, treeset

I am trying to write a program that will utilize the Huffman code. However, when I use the tree set, it wants the parameters of "Char, Integer". I want it to take in a "String, Integer" parameter. What can I do to fix this?

```
   private static void processFile(HashMap<String,Integer> freq)
  {
    TreeSet<Node> trees = new TreeSet<Node>();  

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : freq.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      Integer value = entry.getValue();

      if (value > 0)
      {
        Node n = new Node(key, value);
        trees.add(n);
      }
    }
```

Comment: where does it require a char ?

Comment: Check the constructor of `Node`. make sure it takes a matching types.

Comment: Oh, where I have "key", it says the parameters are "char, Integer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Node n = new Node(key, value);
```

to:

```
Node n = new Node(key.charAt(0), value);
```

I assume that this happens because the `Node` constructor requires a `char` not string.